# How can I change multiple keys in a JSON file that has multiple dictionaries which incorporate the same keys but different values with Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I currently am attempting to edit a JSON file that has multiple listed dictionaries that incorporate the same keys but different values. I would like to change specific keys (the same ones) in every dictionary within the file. How can I do this?

For Example:

"JSON_FILE" [

```
    {"type" : "person", 'attributes" : { "Name" : "Jack, "Age" : 24, "Hight" : 6.2}}

    {"type" : "person", "attributes" : { "Name" : "Brent", "Age" : 15, "Hight" : 5.6}}

    {"type" : "person", "attributes" : { "Name" : "Matt", "Age" : 30, "Hight" : 4.9}}  ]
```

I would like to change all the 'Name' keys to be labeled as " 'NAMES' " and all the 'Hight' keys to be labeled as 'HIGHT (ft)'.

I am using Python and this is a data set of 100 dictionaries I am attempting to edit so going through one at a time is not efficient.

Comment: Are you sure about the quotings of the data in your file?

Comment: this is just an example I typed up. its not the actual data im working with but the question is still the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the schema is actually well-formed ("attributes" in quotes, use of double rather than single quotes, commas between objects in a list).

You can do the following to rename your fields:

```py
import json

data = json.load(open('your_file_name.json', 'r'))
for data_entry in data:
    # Add new 'NAME' field, then delete old 'Name' field.
    data_entry['attributes']['NAME'] = data_entry['attributes']['Name']
    del data_entry['attributes']['Name']

    # Add new 'HIGHT' (sic) field, then delete old 'Hight' field.
    data_entry['attributes']['HIGHT'] = data_entry['attributes']['Hight']
    del data_entry['attributes']['Hight']

with open('your_file_name.json', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: this is very useful but I am attempting to change not 2 but 8 different keys. Do i need to go though all 8 of them like in your example or is there a quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple keys under `attributes` to upper case, you can do the following:

```
import json

file_path = "path/to/file"
fields_to_upper = ["Name", "Hight", "Age"]
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for row in data:
        for field in fields_to_upper:
            row["attributes"][field.upper()] = row["attributes"].pop(field)
with open(file_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data))
```

If you want to upper case all the keys under `attributes`, try:

```
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for row in data:
        for key in row["attributes"].keys():
            row["attributes"][key.upper()] = row["attributes"].pop(key)
with open(file_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: this is also somewhat helpful but I am not only attempting to change the keys to upper case but also completely change some of them keys to different names entirely.

Comment: You can replace `fields_to_upper` with a dictionary containing the fields and the values they should be converted to and iterate over this dict.

Comment: As it seems that you are new to SO, I would like to explain you something - people should not guess what you actually mean if you don't explain it properly in the question. You should provide as much context as possible. In the original question you didn't mention neither that the names should be changed to completely different values nor that it should work for multiple fields.